# How to insert all 118 elements of the periodic table with their symbol and name in a sql database

Tags: android, sql, database

I am developing an android application in which I have made a database having three columns: the primary integer id, the periodic element name and the periodic element symbol. I need to put all 118 elements with their names and symbols as the columns described above as 118 rows. If anyone can help me in doing this in the least time consuming manner.

P.S. I will not be able to manually enter the periodic elements name and symbol in the database by making 118 rows manually. There has to be some automated better solution if anyone can tell me about it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please feel free to describe, in detail, what the characteristics are of your proposed "automated better solution".

Comment: I would like to import it from excel sheet or csv file but dont know how to proceed. I have found the sql database from here http://raw-d.com/blog/?p=358 but the only problem remaining is that the columns in the sql database downloaded from the link are very large. I just need id, name and atomic_symbol column from this database.

Comment: Why not just delete the columns from the database that you already have?  When you say "the columns are too big", this makes no sense.  Do  you mean that it has too many columns, some of which you do not want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you're asking. But if you just want a database table with the periodic elements then check the link:
http://raw-d.com/blog/?p=358

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. I think that will be pretty useful. I just need three columns in my database i.e. id, element name and element symbol and want to delete all other columns. I have been out of touch with sql lately. I will be grateful if you give me a quick solution.

Comment: Sure. You need to brush up on your sql if you want to work with a database. Anyway the easiest way you can do it is: you get the csv file from the link above and remove the unwanted columns, save the file and then import it in sqlite3. Follow the simple instructions here to import: http://sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles

Answer (score 0):

there is no automated solution to do that, you can do this with a multiple sql INSERT statement

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (1,'hydrogen','H');
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (2,'Helium','He');
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (3,'Lithium','Li');
```